# Stacked column inside drilldown - HighCharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Been playing around with Highcharts.js and am trying to get a percent stacked chart working with two levels via a drilldown.  Both levels are pretty much the same with a stacked percentage chart. I can see how to get this working without the drilldown, but I am not sure how to accurately stack at the second level of a drilldown.

here is some code I am working with on jsfiddle so far.  http://jsfiddle.net/QnVPE/5/

To kinda recap. I am trying to show a percentage of how many videos a user has watched and than the grey area (the stacked part) should be the rest of the perentage, how many they havnt watched out of the 100%.

Should be simple but giving me some trouble, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working in case any one else is wondering. here is how i set it up.

http://jsfiddle.net/QnVPE/9/

Comment: hi, I am trying to drill down from column to column range using dates. can you help? http://jsfiddle.net/shorif2000/9tRWW/14/